# Jaxb/Jersey servlet data isn't being returned correctly

Tags: java, tomcat, servlets, jaxb, jersey

I have a small tomcat servlet using Jaxb/Jersey.  The post handler returns an object that contains other objects.  When the result gets back to the caller, the contained objects are mosly null - even though they weren't null in the servlet.

-- servlet --

```
@POST
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML)
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML)
public Response postPlan( JAXBElement<String> mxml) throws IOException {
    iMetrix metrix_MIS = Metrix_MIS_Implementation.getInstance();
    iMetrix_GeneratePlan_Response result = metrix_MIS.generatePlan(mxml.getValue());

    PlanData data = new PlanData();
    data.setJunk("Testing Junk");
    data.setGuid(result.getProjectID());
    data.setLog((Metrix_Log_Implementation) result.getLog());
    InputStream planStream = result.getPlanZipStream();
    if (planStream != null) {
        data.setPlanXML(IOUtils.readFully(planStream, -1, true));
    }

    result.getLog().dump(System.out);

    return Response.ok(data).build();
}
```

--Calling app--

```
        Client client = ClientBuilder.newClient();
    WebTarget web = client.target(url);
    Entity<String> entity = Entity.entity(mxmlProjectString, MediaType.APPLICATION_XML_TYPE);
    Response resp = web.request(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML_TYPE).post(entity);
    int status = resp.getStatus();
    System.out.println(status + "-" + resp.getStatusInfo().toString());
    System.out.println(resp.toString());
    System.out.println(resp.readEntity(String.class));
```

The servlet prints out a bunch of data from getLog().dump() line.
The caller just gets an empty log object:

```
200-OK
InboundJaxrsResponse{ClientResponse{method=POST, uri=http://192.168.187.128:8080/MetrixServer/rest/Plan/v1, status=200, reason=OK}}
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?><planData><junk>Testing Junk</junk><log/></planData>
```

So, what am I missing?

PlanData is:

```
@XmlRootElement
public class PlanData {
  private String                guid;
  private byte[]                planXML;
  private Metrix_Log_Implementation log;
  private String                junk;
... getters/setters left out...
```

Metrix_Log_Implementation:

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "MetrixLog")
public class Metrix_Log_Implementation implements iMetrix_Log {
... stuff...
  @XmlRootElement(name = "LogLine")
  private static class Metrix_LogLine_Implementation implements iMetrix_LogLine {
    private eLogLineType    m_type;
    private String      m_message;
    private String      m_MISID;
... more stuff ...
```

The one oddity, is the private internal class, and the use of an enum.  Shouldn't that work though?

Comment: I'd comment all of the nested classes and enums out to see if you can get any response containing log entries at all... You might also want to add some junk values into those objects just to make sure those objects will be included into input. Once you figured where the problem is, you can go from there.

Comment: That's what I was hoping to avoid, since lots of other classes use these as well.  Too many possibilities of breaking something else.
I ended up just creating a set of very simple data holding classes, and copying the data to/from them.  Those simpler classes converted to/from XML just fine.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure exactly what part of the semi-complex class structure caused the problem.  Sure would be nice if some kind of error msg was generated somewhere.
I just created simple data classes to be transferred, and copied the data to/from the more complex classes at either end.